# What is the analytical solution of the one dimensional Poisson equation?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, hilbert-spaces, sobolev-spaces

I have shown that by Lax-Milgram theorem that the following equation has unique solution.

$$
-u''+u=f~~in~~ \Omega=(0,1)
$$
and boundary conditions are $u(0)=u(1)$ and $u'(0)=u'(1)$.

This is a one dimensional problem and I am trying to write its analytical solution. I am little confused in writing the particular  solution of this problem that satisfies its boundary conditions.

Can anyone please help me with this?

Comment: It is highly unlikely you will be able to find the solution explicitly for general $f$. Do you have a specific $f$ in mind?

Comment: @JackT if I know a specific f then it is easy to find a particular solution. In this question, I don't have specific f.